# How to select an item that is into another item using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

in HTML I have the following structure:

```
    <div class="row" id="info-section">
        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Calendario Eventi</h4></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // 'My_Widgtet_Area' area, where the id is called:
                            if (is_active_sidebar('calendar_widget_zone')) : ?>

                                <div id="widget-sidebar">
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('calendar_widget_zone'); ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div><!-- #widget-sidebar .widget-area -->

                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And now, using CSS I want select (to change a value) of the **.panel-heading** class that is into the **#info-section** div

What can I do to select only the **.panel-heading** item nested into **#info-section** div?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: You should probably go read some literature or take a tutorial on css. I am sure this question has been asked thousands of times already, a quick search would have sufficed to get the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the nested or the in selector:

```
#info-section .panel-heading {
  /* css */
}
```

or you can use the child selector (which means that it should be inside the container, not inside of one of their children)

```
#info-section > .panel-heading {
  /* css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the CSS selector:

```
#info-section .panel-heading{
  //css stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#info-section .panel-heading{
  //Your Style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the yellow brick road :)

CSS

```
#info-section .panel-heading { 
    /* CSS STYLES */
}
```